# How can I detect selection on an Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple ListView that gets populated using an array of `SimpleAdapter`s.

How can I detect selection on this ListView?

Sample code is appreciated...

Comment: If you want to select single item from the list then you can use setOnItemClickListener() method if m not wrong to getting your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [ListView.setOnItemClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
        ... do something based on position ...
    }
});
```